# Nike+ API : Possible to obtain realtime update of ongoing running session?

Tags: nikeplus-api

Is it possible to obtain the realtime update of ongoing running session from Nike+ API ?

I tried to use API call :

```
GET https://api.nike.com/me/sport/activities/
```

but the ongoing running session doesn't exist. However, when the run is ended, the information of the session is shown by the API call.

Is it possible to obtain the ongoing running session's data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible since you're dependent on the activity being synced and the device doesn't sync mid-activity (at the moment!)