# Is there any API to get FuelPoints from Nike Fuel Band ?

Tags: nikeplus-api

I used your Nike+ Running API. Its great. Thanks for that. Is there any API to get FuelPoints from Nike Fuel Band ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an API for that. Head over to https://developer.nike.com/resources to check it out.

Further reading seems to indicate the API is lacking when it comes to grabbing the FuelPoints.

Here is a blog post where they mention doing a workaround to grab this data:
http://blog.amazeelabs.com/en/extracting-fuel-points-nike

And here is a github project that could be helpful as a reference example.
gist.github.com/NorthIsUp/3949465

Comment: I tried all examples . Also If I hit URL like "https://api.nike.com/me/sport/activities/104019031?access_token=test1234" . But there is an error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968786/nike-api-possible-to-obtain-realtime-update-of-ongoing-running-session?rq=1  This post seems to suggest you can only hit that URL after the device is synced.

Comment: You need a real token, not 'test1234' :)

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible, I have a working application that does this. See: http://wildcanyongames.org/nike-fuel.

http://developer.nike.com should have all the info you need, or you can open a more specific question if you have one.